Shuffling 3d numpy array along axis independently
How can i write this code better?
I have 2d array repeated k times along 0-axis. I want to shuffle it independently along the second axis. Code provided below works, but I believe that it can be done better. Please, help.
c = rng.random(size=(n, m))[np.newaxis].repeat(k, axis=0)

for i in range(c.shape[0]):
        c[i] = c[i, rng.choice(c.shape[1], c.shape[1], replace=False)]

I tried multiple setups with slicing and permuting slices on 2d arrays but i can't image this on 3d array.

Please provide some code to generate a representative c array.

c = rng.random(size=(n, m))[np.newaxis].repeat(k, axis=0)

Please edit your question to include that.

Does this answer your question? Shuffling NumPy array along a given axis

I believe the duplicate answers your question. Specifically, the answer that suggests rng.permuted. In your case: rng.permuted(c, axis=-1, out=c).

Small example:
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()

n = 4
m = 3
k = 2

c = rng.random(size=(k, n, m))

c is:
array([[[0.41020744, 0.10595292, 0.77565636],
        [0.81389261, 0.66003734, 0.01037299],
        [0.93920543, 0.384785  , 0.05543084],
        [0.30460909, 0.40248868, 0.39469976]],

       [[0.97808845, 0.19421067, 0.56014205],
        [0.31257343, 0.95297191, 0.14725328],
        [0.47446104, 0.66471068, 0.00975436],
        [0.04586853, 0.46771096, 0.5393846 ]]])

Note that its shape is preserved from before.
